# When to use touchmove vs mousemove?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousemove, touchmove

I build a web mobile game, it runs on browsers (PC/Mobile).

Do I need to use the `touchmove` or not?

How can I run the `touchmove` event like the `mousemove` event?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For parity between desktop and touch you have the following equivalences:

```js
mousedown === touchstart
mousemove === touchmove
mouseup === touchend
```

Thus if you handle `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` then you don't need to handle the corresponding equivalent events under touch. The same handlers should be executing.

Comment: That is right, BUT : <br/> if you add the touch events it will NOT work like the mouse events. <br/> What we make for the touch mobile phone will NOT run on the PC.

Comment: Shouldn'd be (Mousemove && (MousedownHasFired && MouseupHasNotYetBeFired)) === TouchMove?

Comment: That's not true, 
mousemove ~= touchmove

With mousemove, it take the hovered element but with touchmove it takes the first touched element.

Comment: what can i do if i  need below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934867/touch-move-working-diffrently-than-mousemove

Comment: It appears as if the last paragraph is a slight over-simplification. I have implemented `mousedown` + `mousemove` + `mouseup`, but when I use my app on a touch device, none of them fire. This may be either (1) browser-specific, (2) due to synthetic event handler behavior in React, or perhaps (3) a result of some CSS properties like e.g. [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action). Any clarification under which circumstances this statement holds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Except on the ipad -- where  mouse hover, mouse down, mouse up and click are all triggered... except if you change anything in mouse hover .. then nothing else gets triggered.... very annoying...more details see http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use both in one component (w.r.t react)
for eg:
`<component onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onTouchMove={handleMouseMove} />`
on the bases of screen which is being used react will automatically switch either option of mouse or touch
or you can also use
`("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)`
it gives true for touch screen device and vice versa
ref: https://codepen.io/tteske/pen/KKwxOxp