# Replace mousemove with touchmove event

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, mousemove, touchmove

My program recognizes the `mousemove event`. What I would like to do is make my program work for mobile.

That is why I would like to transform the mousemove event to a `touchmove event`.

My code is like this so far:

```
var d=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
$hit=$("#hit");
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

tolerance = 20;
function handleMouseMove(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  var isHit=d[(mouseY*cw+mouseX)*4+3]>tolerance;

  if(isHit){
    $hit.text("Yeahhhh");
  }else{
    //document.onmousemove = crash;
    $hit.text("Noooooooo");
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I can do that easily?

I have read that is equivalent [When to use touchmove vs mousemove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510999/when-to-use-touchmove-vs-mousemove) but I am not sure how to handle the `mouseX` and the `mouseY`.

Comment: use a touch library like [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) or [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for handle touch events.. the event objects will have all the info you'll need...

Answer (score 0):

[toe.js](http://damien.antipa.at/2012/07/18/toe-js-extensible-touch-gestures/) - a lightweight touch events library, works pretty well. Hammerjs definitely has more customization, but toejs looked simpler.

and have a suggestion in your code to avoid unnecessary event.stopPropagation, see [here](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery UI Touch Punch for hack jquery events

read this:http://touchpunch.furf.com/