# jQuery - mousemove for Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to recreate the same effect showed below on mobile devices.
I have tried to use `.vmousemove` however, the `div` only move when I touch and realise. What I am trying to achieve is that the `div` follows the finger movement on screen.

Is this something possible to achieve with jQuery?
Also I can  I centre the mouse in the middle of the `div`?

```js
   $('#cont').mousemove(function(e) {

     var offs = $(this).offset(),
       p = {
         x: offs.left,
         y: offs.top
       },
       mPos = {
         x: e.pageX,
         y: e.pageY
       },
       x = mPos.x - p.x - 100,
       y = mPos.y - p.y - 100;
     $('.gray', this).css({
       left: x,
       top: y,
       backgroundPosition: -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px'
     });

   });
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.gray {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('img/grid.png');
  opacity: 0.9;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#5defb2+0,edd92d+46,d156ea+57,7eea9b+100 */
  background: rgb(93, 239, 178);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(93, 239, 178, 1) 0%, rgba(237, 217, 45, 1) 46%, rgba(209, 86, 234, 1) 57%, rgba(126, 234, 155, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(93, 239, 178, 1) 0%, rgba(237, 217, 45, 1) 46%, rgba(209, 86, 234, 1) 57%, rgba(126, 234, 155, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(93, 239, 178, 1) 0%, rgba(237, 217, 45, 1) 46%, rgba(209, 86, 234, 1) 57%, rgba(126, 234, 155, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5defb2', endColorstr='#7eea9b', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont">
  <div class="gray"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510999/when-to-use-touchmove-vs-mousemove

Comment: Thank you, I have noted that post however, I have the same result using `touch move`, the div does not follow the finger

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517924/javascript-mapping-touch-events-to-mouse-events

Comment: U should may add JavaScript timer to your code and run your oart of code int it

Answer (score 0):

```
 var timer;
$('#cont').mousemove(function(e) {
   timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
var offs = $(this).offset(),
       p = {
         x: offs.left,
         y: offs.top
       },
       mPos = {
         x: e.pageX,
         y: e.pageY
       },
       x = mPos.x - p.x - 100,
       y = mPos.y - p.y - 100;
     $('.gray', this).css({
       left: x,
       top: y,
       backgroundPosition: -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px'
     });
 },10000)
   return false; 
})
```

I am not sure if it works or not just idea